# How can i resolve the Internal React error?

Tags: react-native

I keep getting an Error message anytime my splash screen runs and redirects to a new screen
Warning: Internal React error: Attempted to capture a commit phase error inside a detached tree. This indicates a bug in React. Likely causes include deleting the same fiber more than once, committing an already-finished tree, or an inconsistent return pointer.

I tried running "npm install" for fix all dependencies but no results

Comment: Is this a fresh project or does it have any logic happening on the splash screen ? Maybe it would be better if you include any relevant code  in your question.

Comment: Did you fix this? I got same error today :(

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have some `useEffect` that do "things" inside your component that loads before everything.

Or maybe an import that is not marked as "invalid" (such as `react-native/types`) but actually causes many problems (should be just `react-native`).

Or you're returning some wrong objects in your render (like using an object `{myView}` instead of `<MyView />`).

Check with `npm outdated` if you have any packages to update: do not update it "as is", but check compatibility.